# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the REDIS_URL environment variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pythonanywhere, cookiecutter-django

I used Django-Cookiecutter to boost start my Django development. Now after building the website and wanting to host it, my choice was python anywhere and that's because I have already hosted a website there but that website wasn't built using Django-Cookiecutter. To host It on python anywhere am currently following the [Django-Cookiecutter Official docs to host on pythonanywhere](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-on-pythonanywhere.html)  I have completed the first steps till it's time to run python manage.py migrate which results in the following error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the REDIS_URL environment variable

In Full The Error Msg is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 273, in get_value
value = self.ENVIRON[var]
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'REDIS_URL'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 35, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 82, in wrapped
saved_locale = translation.get_language()
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 252, in get_language
return _trans.get_language()
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
if settings.USE_I18N:
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/someone/proj/config/settings/production.py", line 26, in <module>
"LOCATION": env("REDIS_URL"),
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 123, in __call__
return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default)
File "/home/someone/.virtualenvs/smt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 277, in get_value
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the REDIS_URL environment variable

When I tried other manage.py commands like python manage.py collectstatic they resulted with the same error msg.

Answer (score 3):

By default it seems that Django-Cookiecutter expects a redis instance in production for caching (https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/config/settings/production.py#L34). If you do not have redis set up, update the `CACHES` setting to use a different cache backend and remove the sentry `RedisIntegration`.

Comment: I Don't know how to thank you. THANKS! MUCH APPRECIATED!